# FxCop Abstract types should not have constructors when no new

Tags: .net, vb.net, fxcop, abstract

I have an issue with FxCop and the warning: `Abstract types should not have constructors`.

This is being displayed for a number of abstract classes (possibly all, I haven't checked).  When I look most of them have no new method so I assume it's the complier adding a default one.   So to remove it I add a private default constuctor (`Private Sub New()`), this then means all the inherting classes fail to build with the error: 
`Class 'InheritingClass' has no accessible 'Sub New' and cannot be inherited.`

This seems odd as FxCop requests no public constructor, but when I remove it the build fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a *protected*, parameterless constructor to the abstract class instead.

When you don't provide a constructor, the compiler adds a *public*, parameterless one for you. Clearly, it isn't appropriate for an abstract class to have public constructors since they are *effectively*  protected anyway - constructors on abstract types can *at best* be called by subclasses (that's the whole point of an abstract type - it can't be instantiated 'vanilla'). This design flaw is what causes FxCop to complain.

On the other hand, the step you took to fix the issue was too extreme; classes (abstract or not) that have *only* private constructors are not subclassable in practice (except by a nested class) - there is no implicit or explicit `base(...)` constructor-call that could possibly work in a derived class's constructor.

EDIT: I like the way [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182126%28VS.80%29.aspx) puts it:

> In the example above abstract type has
>   a public constructor, which can
>   confuse users. They see the public
>   constructor, but do not understand why
>   they are unable to create the type.